# How TO Use NSArray objectAtIndex: shorthand

Tags: ios5

### > [Is there some literal dictionary or array syntax in Objective-C?]

An Objective-C subscript expression occurs when the base operand of the C subscript operator has an Objective-C object pointer type. Since this potentially collides with pointer arithmetic on the value, these expressions are only supported under the modern Objective-C runtime, which categorically forbids such arithmetic

I have recently noticed that something strange seems to work in objective-c.

When I have an array,

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"1", @"b", @"3", @"d"];
```

I can normally access the second element by,

```
NSString *element = [myArray objectAtIndex:2];
```

however I seem to now also be able to access it via.

```
NSString *element = myArray[2];
```

Does anyone know if this is now a defined behaviour and therefore safe to use, or should I avoid it? Thanks to anyone who can help!!

Comment: Yes, it is defined behavior, after some (in the past) version of Xcode.  You can also do `myDictonary[@"myKey"]`.

Comment: ok i m trying  i will give you my feedback after some time